# Injecting CSS String as New Document Stylesheet

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom, iframe

I am dynamically creating a large stylesheet as a string and desiring to injecting it into an iframe. Initially I approached it like this:

```
var css = '.newstyle { margin: 20px; } .newstyle2 { margin: 20px; }';
$('iframe').contents().find('head').append('<style type="text/css">'+css+'</style>');
```

Unfortunately, IE7 does not like this method. I'm not sure how else to approach this injection. Is there a cross-browser solution that will enable me to inject a mass of CSS from a string?

Comment: Try the non-jQuery solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158370/injected-link-stylesheet-takes-precedence-over-existing-styles-in-ie7

Comment: I am looking to not use the <link /> tag to reduce the amount of http requests. Speed is key in this script.

Comment: Try injecting the css into the body... I seem to remember IE being fussy about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `document.stylesheets` for this purpose. It gives you access to the style sheets within a page.

Check this article: http://kentbrewster.com/creating-dynamic-stylesheets/ — It's a bit older and not jQuery–centric, but I'm sure you can adjust it to your needs. I've used this technique a few years back and I believe it worked fine in all browsers after tweaking a bit.

Here's a bit more information on the `stylesheets` property:

- http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/changess.html
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.styleSheets